# Rewriting names (rearranging and modifying strings)

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to write a code that given a name returns the name with the last name first, followed by a comma, followed by the first name (if any), followed by the first letter of each remaining/middle name with a period after each letter. If a middle name is a single letter, do not abbreviate it/follow it by a period.

I've gotten it to work for the basics (i.e. Karen Anne Carpenter --> Carpenter, Karen A. (code for that not shown) but how to I make it work for Bryan J Phil K Smith --> Smith, Bryan J P. K? (no period for one letter middle names).

```
def rewrite(name):
    space = " "
    l = [i for i in range(len(name)) if name.startswith(" ", i, i+1)] #i gives index of every space, l[i] gives list of these indexes
    for i in range(len(l)-1): 
        if name[l[i]+2] == " ": #middle name is only one letter, print name[l[i]+1] as is
            shortMiddleInitial = name[l[i] + 1]
    #missing return?
        if name[l[i]+2] != " ": #middle name is more than one letter, take initial and period
            middleInitial = name[l[i] + 1] + "."
    #missing return?
```

Comment: You will need to work harder with people with multi-word surnames e.g de la Rue, van't Hoff etc

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
def rewrite(name):
    parts = name.split()
    lastname = parts[-1]
    if len(parts) > 1:
        firstname = parts[0]
    else:
        return lastname  # if no firstname there are no middles, just return
    if len(parts) > 2:
        # If you don't want 1-letter middle names to be followed by a "." change it to "len > 1".
        middles = [c[0] + '.' if len(c) >= 1 else c for c in parts[1:-1]]
    else:
        middles = []
    return '{}, {} {}'.format(lastname, firstname, ' '.join(middles)).strip()
```

This works for several inputs:

```
>>> rewrite('Bryan J Phil K Smith')
'Smith, Bryan J. P. K.'

>>> rewrite('Karen Anne Carpenter')
'Carpenter, Karen A.'

>>> rewrite('Funny')
'Funny'

>>> rewrite('Pete Funny')
'Funny, Pete'
```